# QDateEdit validations

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying validate two QDateEdits. I have two fields, `startdate` and `enddate` and I want to validate that the minimum date of `enddate` be the selected `startdate` date. But also, I want to give the user the opportunity for the `enddate` field to be empty.
I connected both fields,

```
connect(startDate,SIGNAL(dateChanged(QDate)),endDate,SLOT(setMinDate(QDate)));
```

`startDate` and `endDate` are `QDateEdit` with a popup calendar.

So, where is the problem here? When I click over endDate the minimum date is ok but the next day (first valid date) appears in blue color like it was selected, but when I clicked over that date the popup closed and the date is not set. For example:

When I open the form the `startdate` field have by default the current date. Later I click over `endDate` field and the minimum allowed date is one more day which is ok, but this minimum allowed date is blue marked and when I clicked the date is not set.

Sorry if my English is so bad, I hope that you can help me. Thanks any way

Comment: Please provide some code.

Answer (score 2):

I found what my problem is. I connected the slot to `dateChanged(QDate)` signal, so, by default the `QDateEdit` set the first allowed date as selected, so if you select it again the signal it's not emited and by result the date it's not set. My solution is use `editingFinished()` signal instead `dateChanged(QDate)` signal. I hope has been helpful. Regards,